# .Net DataAnnotations Unique Index with Display attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations

I am using EF 6+ version to create Code First database. However during unit testing I stumbled upon interesting fact. Th attribute `Index(IsUnique = true)` doesn't really like to be together with `Display` attribute.

```
[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
[StringLength(150)]
[Required]
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), Name = "Program")]
public String Name { get; set; }
```

I have such property in my Entity with all those Data Annotations and Display attribute. When I am trying to add second entity with the same name to db it passes without throwing any exception. But when I comment out Display attribute thane I have exception `DbUpdateException`.

Is `Display` somehow overriding `Index Unique`, or maybe it is causing validation to not check unique index? Or maybe value from resource string is somehow causing  ambiguity that Validation cannot handle?

Comment: The DisplayAttribute is something for displaying of the entity class. It shouldn't related to db schema change. The DbUpdateException looks like be thrown when you change something in DB. Since you use code-first, you can create a new migration after commenting out the line for [Display(....)] and see if there is anything in the method 'Up' in that migration.

Comment: post the innerexception of your DbUpdateException. the root one